# Make Category Base Appear in Posts Permalink (but not tags)

Tags: permalinks

I have a slight problem with WP permalink structure.

My aim is to make posts permalink appear with a specific category and it's base, for example:

`domain.com/custom-base/%category%/%postname%`

And categories should appear as:

`domain.com/custom-base/%category%`

Problem is that when I specify a category base in permalink settings the posts doesn't "**take**" that base and shows this:

```
domain.com/%category%/%postname%
```

The problem seems to be solved when I manually add that base near custom structure as:

```
domain.com/custom-base/%category%/%postname%
```

But then all the other links (including tags) has that structure which I don't need:

```
domain.com/custom-base/tag/%tag%
```

So my main question is how can I achieve my goal of posts and categories without affecting anything else:

**Post:**

```
domain.com/custom-base/%category%/%postname%
```

**Category:**

```
domain.com/custom-base/%category%
```

Thanks a lot! :)